Bike starts and runs only on reserve Any idea? Bike -Bullet 350 2015 model
Hello My bike starts only when reserve is on. I got my bikes spark plug clean. Air filter and engine oil were changed last month drove barely 200kms. Any idea how could this issue be solved

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Is this new behavior? If so, when did it start? Was it after any other events, like fueling up at a different place than you normally would? How long after you change from reserve to regular does it die?

I think it started mainly after I practiced engine breaking. I'm fueling up mostly at the same place. As soon as I change from reserve within a minute it dies.

It runs just fine on reserve for as long as you have it on reserve? (and there's gas in the tank, of course)

I don't know about this specific bike, but the normal fuel supply from some fuel tanks is a separate outlet at a higher level, leaving some fuel in reserve when the tap is switched to the lower outlet. Perhaps the regular fuel passage is blocked and needs clearing.
